# Sublime Text 2 - OS X Command Line problems

Tags: macos, bash, sublimetext2

I'm going through some Ruby tutorials and trying to get Sublime Text 2 setup in the command line in OSX. I have made

```
mkdir ~/bin
```

and then typed in my command line

```
ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" ~/bin/subl
```

and then entered

```
export PATH="$PATH:~/bin"
```

Also, in SB2, I saved

```
.bash_profile
```

in ~/bin

So when I type

```
 subl --help
```

I get

```
-bash: subl: command not found
```

I've been stuck on this for a while and need help. I checked some similar threads and ran through those directions but I'm stumped and feeling noobish than ever. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

PS. I'm using Mavericks.

Comment: Waymond. Please try to tag your questions correctly. This is neither a ruby, nor a ruby-on-rails question. It is, a sublimetext2 question.

Comment: I'll edit it now. Sorry.

Comment: your `.bash_profile` should be in your home directory (`~`), not in `~/bin`.

Comment: Thanks! I deleted it and tried running it. Still the same results. Any advice?

    -bash: subl: command not found

Comment: Try running this: `sudo ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /usr/bin/subl` - this will create the symlink in `/usr/bin`, which is already in your default path. `sudo` requires your password. Next, run `which subl` and it should return `/usr/bin/subl`. You should then be able to run `subl --help` and get the output you're looking for.

Comment: It said that the file already exists. I tried subl --help and it still can't find the command. I hate to do it but should I reformat my whole system?

Comment: Try `hash -r`. That checks for executables in your path again. Or just open a new terminal window.

Comment: I kind of got it. Instead of typing subl, I have to type Sublime. Not a problem but I would like to figure out why I can't type subl. I followed this person's tutorial [link](https://gist.github.com/olivierlacan/1195304)

Comment: because of the following line in that tutorial - the last argument is your shortcut: `ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text\ 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/local/bin/sublime` note that __sublime__ there at the end is the link you're creating _from_ the subl file

Comment: @amp Thanks for pointing that out! Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for mavericks:

$ > printenv | grep bin

$ PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin

**Create the symbolic link:**

$ sudo ln -sf "/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /usr/bin/subl